# Data Vs information

Tags: orthography

We have been using this for quite a long time,but still I need the minute difference so that I can use it based on context perfectly

Comment: For those who are down voting my question I would be happy if they can give the reason for it also

Comment: I haven't down voted it, but I have recommended a close. All questions should show evidence of research. As a starting point to answer this you could have checked the two meanings of these words in a dictionary. If you have done that, you should have included what you found out in your question, and discussed what confused you about the two definitions.

Comment: I suspect this is downvoted because **it isn't a question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"data" is essentially a collection of facts (although it has a slightly different meaning in IT) and not directly useful. Information is useful and is often described as 'processed data' (although 'meaningfully processed data' would be more accurate). Many people, though, use the two terms interchangeably.

If you want more than that, you will need to expand your question. Both these words can be found in dictionaries, but I am unsure exactly what differences you are looking for, or which definitions you are using.

Comment: Updated..Thanks!!.now to all those new readers stop giving me negative marks...

Comment: @user268902 where have you updated your question? Downvotes can be reversed, and thought-provoking questions are highly valued and  upvoted on EL&U

Comment: @mari I respect that thought wholeheartedly.i got the answer that I was looking for hence will not be discussing regarding this further.

Comment: @user268902 then you can thank Lee John by accepting their answer. Click on the grey checkmark below the arrow.

Comment: I guess you are quite interested to show your superiority in this small conversation itself.anyhow I'll give it to you.btw thank you Lee.